# Difference between "postularse a" and "postularse para"

Tags: preposiciones

Is there any difference between "postularse a" and "postularse para" ? Example:

> Mi padre se postuló a/para senador.

Comment: i think you will use the "a" to indicate "who" and "para" to indicate "to" 

for example "postularon a jose" and "jose se postulo para"

Comment: What does "postularon a Jose" mean?

Comment: I agree with @Mike that "para" will usually introduce the position (though "a" can also be informally used with that function). "a" will generally introduce the person being proposed, for example: *El presidente postuló **a** su hijo **para** el cargo de embajador.* We can also use "como": *El presidente postuló **a** su hijo **como** embajador.*

Comment: @AlanEvangelista "postularon a juan" means : "juan was postulated"

Comment: @Mike that meaning makes no sense in this context. "to postulate" = to suggest or assume the existence or truth of something as a basis for further reasoning. From the example given by Gustavson above, I think you meant "to nominate" or "to propose" instead.

Comment: Word Reference (https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=postular) says that "postular a" is used as "postular para" in Latin America. Ex: De las diez personas que se postularon a la presidencia, solo tres tienen opciones de ganar. That's the context I meant in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*“Postularse para X”* is equivalent to *“postularse a X”* (where *X* is a post). This can be the title given to the person occupying the post (*presidente, senador*, etc.) or the name of the office (*la presidencia, la senaduría*) or something more general like *una banca en la Cámara de Diputados* ("a seat in the Chamber of Deputies/Representatives"). According to your source, the usage with the preposition *a* is Latin American, and we're left to assume that the usage with *para* is European. In my experience (I'm Argentinian) both are used, but *para* sounds more formal.

> *Juan se postuló para un escaño en el Senado.*
>   *María se postula a la presidencia.*

If you use the title you can also employ *como*:

> *Juan se postuló como senador.*
>   *María se postula como presidenta.*

You can also use *postularse* with an infinitive subordinate phrase; in this case you can only use *para*:

> *Juan se postuló para ocupar un escaño en el Senado.*
>   *María se postula para llegar a la presidencia.*

Note that this holds for *postularse*, the pronominal version of the verb. The basic verb *postular*, which means "to nominate", takes as its direct object the person that is nominated. Direct objects are preceded by *a* when they are animate, so *“postular a Z”* (where *Z* is a person) means "to nominate *Z*". If you choose to mention the office to which *Z* is nominated, you can use *para* or *a* (yes, *a* again), or *como* if you use the title:

> *El partido postuló a Juan al Senado.*
>   *La asamblea postula a María para la presidencia.*
>   *Queremos postular a José como nuestro representante.*